# Outlook 2010 VBA to c# conversion

Tags: c#, vba, outlook

I'm trying to convert a bit of VBA (outlook) to c# for an addin. Struggling with it. The code changes the account dropdown on the reply/replyall/forward form in outlook. Now I have to type more useless stuff because the editor is moaning about more code than text. I have converted 99% of it.

```
public string Set_Account(string AccountName, Outlook.MailItem M)
    {
        string tempSet_Account = null;
        Outlook.Inspector OLI = null;
        string strAccountBtnName = null;
        int intLoc = 0;
        const int ID_ACCOUNTS = 31224;

        Office.CommandBars CBs = null;
        Office.CommandBarPopup CBP = null;
        Office.CommandBarControl MC = null;

        M.Display();

        OLI = M.GetInspector;
        if (OLI != null)
        {
            CBs = OLI.CommandBars;
            CBP = CBs.FindControl(, ID_ACCOUNTS); // This line errors and I can't find what goes in it to make it work
            CBP.Reset();
            if (CBP != null)
            {
                foreach (Office.CommandBarControl MCWithinLoop in CBP.Controls)
                {
                    MC = MCWithinLoop;
                    intLoc = MCWithinLoop.Caption.IndexOf(" ") + 1;
                    if (intLoc > 0)
                    {
                        strAccountBtnName = MCWithinLoop.Caption.Substring(intLoc);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strAccountBtnName = MCWithinLoop.Caption;
                    }
                    if (strAccountBtnName == AccountName)
                    {
                        MCWithinLoop.Execute();
                        tempSet_Account = AccountName;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        tempSet_Account = "";

        MC = null;
        CBP = null;
        CBs = null;
        OLI = null;
        return tempSet_Account;
    }
```

**I am having trouble with this line specifically**:

```
CBP = CBs.FindControl(, ID_ACCOUNTS);
```

It fails and says it needs a type "MsoControlType" but I cannot find any control type that fits. It seems in VBA you can findcontrol with just one entry (the other being blank) In C# you need 2. Every thing I put it the compiler moans about

> cannot convert Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoControlType.msoCommandBarControl to ...msoCommandBarPopup

But I cannot find a reference to it anywhere.

Comment: Nobody will convert a whole piece of code for you. You need to attempt it for yourself, and if you have problems with specific parts of it then you can come here and ask for some assistance... but not for all this code

Comment: Yeah done most of it - one line giving me problems - edited first post

Comment: And which line is that?

Comment: Added it to the first post - I was in the process of editing it when you replied. -  thanks Steve

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can't leave out a parameter like you're doing here: ".FindControl(,". If you have to pass "null" or a null object.

Comment: It still moans - cannot implicitly convert type Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoControlType.msoCommandBarControl to ...msoCommandBarPopup.

Comment: It seems that Findcontrol in C# only returns a CommandBarControl and I need a CommandBarPopup in the original VBA code.

Comment: Note from MS docs: "Every pop-up control contains a CommandBar object. To return the command bar from a pop-up control, apply the CommandBar property to the CommandBarPopup object."

Comment: Do you need to do an explicit cast?

Comment: No idea that's why i am here

Comment: "Every pop-up control contains a CommandBar object. To return the command bar from a pop-up control, apply the CommandBar property to the CommandBarPopup object." ---- how?